# Two plugin modify one doctrine entity for sylius

Tags: sylius

I started to study Sylius, and I can't find answer for my question.

**For example**

I have two plugin. PluginOne, PluginTwo. Installing it into composer trought private repository (for example: saits)
I have one Doctrine Entity Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product

Each on my plugin customize model Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product.

**For example**

PluginOne - added field guid into entity
PluginTwo - added filed content_hash into entity

How can I do it?
I follow this docs
https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/customization/model.html
But can't find answer for my question.

Comment: Can you specify these plugins, which uses one entity? I would like to reproduce this situation

Comment: @Dr. X I think its a theoretical question about the concept of Sylius. I wondered about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed several reusable Sylius plugins. I found that the most convenient way to extend core models is by following these rules:

1. Sylius core models could only be extended in your project's `src/` folder.
2. 3rd party plugins could have traits for core model extension.
3. This should be described in 3rd party plugin's README.md

For example:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Acme\OrderPlugin\Model\OrderInterface as AcmeOrderPluginOrderInterface;
use Acme\OrderPlugin\Model\OrderTrait as AcmeOrderPluginTrait;
use Acme\PromotionPlugin\Model\Traits\OrderGiftPromotionTrait as AcmePromotionPluginGiftPromotionTrait;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Order as BaseOrder;

class Order extends BaseOrder implements AcmeOrderPluginOrderInterface
{
    use AcmeOrderPluginTrait;
    use AcmePromotionPluginGiftPromotionTrait;
}
```